# Facebook Marketing API connections: exclude people

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

So on the Ads Manager under connections, it gives you the choice to exclude people who used your app as a way to avoid showing ads to your current users.

The marketing API in the doc says you can set a targeting spec: 'app_install_state' which can be set to 'INSTALLED' or 'NOT_INSTALLED' and to quote facebook

> must be used in conjunction with promoted_object at adset level

I have tried adding it to the $targeting object as well as adding it on the adset level. But when I go to view the ad set in the ad manager on Facebook the connections part is still unchanged.

```
'name' => 'Test Ad Set',
'billing_event' => 'APP_INSTALLS',
'optimization_goal' => 'APP_INSTALLS',
'campaign_status' => "PAUSED",
'daily_budget' => 5000,
'bid_amount' => 10,
'campaign_group_id' => $id,
'targeting' => json_encode($targeting),

$targeting = array(
    'geo_locations' => array(
        'countries' => array('US'),
    ),
    'page_types' => array('mobilefeed'),
    'user_os' => array('Android'),
    'app_install_state' => 'NOT_INSTALLED',
);
```

Also tried moving the app_install_state outside of the targeting array to the adset level.

Incase you don't know what am talking about this is the part on the ad manager:
[image]

Comment: Are you using v2.4 of the Marketing API? From the documentation I see that it must be used in conjunction with promoted_object at adset level - What is your promoted_object and where have you set it?

Comment: Hi Darren, I tried adding it to promoted obj array with no luck before. I also tried adding it to the targeting with no luck.
The promoted obj being where the application ID and object_store_url is set.